# Xcode 7.1 autocomplete not working

Tags: ios, autocomplete, swift2, xcode7

Autocomplete not working in GameScene.swift and GameViewController.swift

What can I do?

Comment: Already deleted DerivedData and caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode

Comment: Please add details and context to your question, it's too vague.